# PostgreSQL export geometry to .sql file

Tags: gdal, postgresql, sql, database

I don't know how to export the geometry of tables in a .sql format from PostgreSQL database. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried pg_dump?

Comment: i dont know how i can make a pg_dump of an individual table. I just know how to dump the entire db and that leads to error when uploading to MySQL

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for exporting one table is the following

```bsh
pg_dump --format plain --verbose --file /path/to_export.sql --table your_table_name your_db_name`
```

Be aware that most SQL syntax is common between database engines but because of some differences, do not expect to reuse a PostgreSQL dump within MySQL. You may experience failure to import.

You should better use `ogr2ogr` GDAL utility for this intent as you can take a PostgreSQL/PostGIS table as input and output to a MySQL table. You should borrow syntax from https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/mysql.html and https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/pg.html to find out the exact syntax `ogr2ogr` command needed.